# Parallel processes overwriting progress bars (tqdm)

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, parallel-processing, tqdm

I am writing a a script in Python 3.7 that launches several parallel tasks using `multiprocessing.Process` (a task per core). To track down the progress for each process, I used the library `tqdm` which implements a progress bar. My code looks like the following:

```
with tqdm(total=iterator_size) as progress_bar:
     for row in tqdm(batch):
         process_batch(batch)
         progress_bar.update(1)
```

The progress bar is indeed updated accordingly, but since multiple processes run the code above, each one overwrites the bar on the console, as the screenshot below illustrates.

[image]

Upon finishing, the console correctly displays the completed progress bars:

[image]

**My goal is to have the progress bars updating without overwriting each other. Is there a way I can achieve this?**

A possible solution would be to only display the progress bar on the process that's gonna take the longest (I know before hand which one is), but the best case scenario would be to have one for each process updating according to the second image.

All the solutions online address `multiprocess.Pool`, but I don't plan to change my architecture, since I can get the most out of `multiprocess.Process`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For updating without overwriting you need to use the `position` parameter of tqdm, which you can find [here](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#nested-progress-bars). Here, `position=0` for the outermost bar, `position=1` for the next, and so on where 0 and 1 are the number of lines to be skipped before printing the progress bar i.e. 0 means progress bar after 0 lines and 1 means after 1 line. As `position` takes the number of lines to be skipped, it requires the index of the process which we can get using `multiprocessing.current_process`

(NOTE: Don't input the `pid` number as it will skip that many lines before printing)

```
from multiprocessing import current_process

""" Your code Here
Here, the current_process() is the process object
current_process().name gives the name of the process
current_process()._identity gives a tuple of the number of process
"""

current = current_process()
with tqdm(total=iterator_size) as progress_bar:
    for row in tqdm(batch, desc=str(current.name),
              position=current._identity[0] - 1)):
        process_batch(batch)
        progress_bar.update(1)
```

Comment: First time I hear about this, sounds interesting. I will give it a try. Thanks for your insight! Will mark as accepted upon testing.

Comment: Thank you, for more information you can refer to the nested progress bars section of the [git hub page of tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#nested-progress-bars)

Comment: Hi, can you please update me on the results of your testing. If it was successful please mark it as accepted or if it failed please inform me so that I can find the right solution.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips on both position & ._identity.  Works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your progress bar inside you parallel loop by using **update**

```
def func(x, pbar):
    for el in batch:
        do_something_with_el(el)
        pbar.update(1)

with tqdm(total=len(your_list)) as pbar:
    batches = np.array_split(your_list, how_many_batches)
    Parallel(n_jobs=-1, prefer='threads')(delayed(func)(batch, pbar)
        for batch in batches)
```

This won't spawn many progress bars

Comment: This crashes for me. `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '(originated from OpenProcess)'`, followed by `psutil.AccessDenied: (pid=3388)`, then by `joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.`

Comment: @Dženan if you got segmentation fault it means you are trying to allocate more memory than you need (i.e. too many processes at once). Try to reduce n_jobs

Answer (score 0):

There is a library [parallelbar](https://pypi.org/project/parallelbar/) that shows the progress bar out of the box. You can track the progress for each core. This works both in the console and in jupiter notebook. The operating system is also not important.